# Passing variable to third page

Tags: php, html

MY Problem is that i have a link on a PAGE 1 with a variable associated with it 
for ex

```
<a href="product.php?family=Spring">Spring</a>
```

when user click this link i forward him to an html page Say PAGE 2 containing registration form when he fills form and click submit the details of form the data he inserted is grabbed by another php page Say PAGE 3 with request.

What i want is that the Variable associated with the link (Spring) on Page 1 may also be passed to this third page where the form data and the variable associated with link on page 1 may be processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your registration page extension to .php and then inside form include an hidden field like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="family" id="family" value="<?php echo $_GET["family"];?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is take the passed data from the link (Spring) and keep the in the hidden field as below. You will need php `$_GET` array for this and your page should have `.php` extension.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Spring" value="Spring value">
<input type="hidden" name="Spring2" value="Spring value 2">
```

Keep the hidden input fields within your registration form. When the registration form is submitted these hidden filed will be submitted along with the form. Then you can retrive them as you are now retrieving the registation values.

Comment: An this one too Thanx @Dasun

Answer (score 0):

Take one hiddne field in registration form such as

```
<input type="hidden" name="passed_var" value="<?php echo $_GET['family']; ?>" />
```

Comment: well i was faster to answer than Ripa even Dasun is more faster then me too...lol just kidding...welcome bro,

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to look into Sessions in order to this

Sessions are Superglobals that can be activated by using the PHP

```
session_start()
```

command.

You can then store and access the SESSION variables like this:

PAGE1.PHP

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = "bar";
?>
```

PAGE2.PHP

```
<?php
session_start()
$foobar = $_SESSION['foo'];

echo $foobar;
//echo's: "bar";

?>
```

You can read more about Sessions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)